# Why is my C code skipping the next user input?

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert my Caesar Cipher code from taking a user given argument to using a user given input, but it's not going the way I've intended at all. I have this code, and it asks the first input for the ROT number, but then it skips the input for the rest of the code. Now, if I wanted to rotate by 2 and use the string bB, the output should be dD, and it is, but only if, when aksed for the input, you put "2 bB". I don't know why this is, and I've looked at other threads saying to just put scanf("%c", &blah);, but I don't know how to do this in my situation. Any help is thankful.

Edit: Changed char to int, as I did in my code just before I posted this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
/**********************************************************************************************************************************/
    int bytesRead;
    int nbytes = 255;
    char *encryptString;
    encryptString = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
    //char encryptString[256];
    char finalChar;
    char finalString[256];
    int rotNum;
/**********************************************************************************************************************************/    
puts("Please enter the ROT (rotate) number you wish to encrypt by: ");
scanf("%d", &rotNum);

printf("Please enter the phrase you'd like to encrypt: \n");
fgets(encryptString, sizeof(encryptString), stdin);
printf("The string entered is: %s\n", encryptString);
printf("The encrypted version is: ");

int n = strlen(encryptString) - 1;

int i;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){     //For loop to go through the entire string entered
    if(isupper(encryptString[i])){
        finalChar = (((encryptString[i] - 65) + rotNum) % 26) + 65;
        finalString[i] = toupper(finalChar);
        //printf("%c\n", finalChar);
    }

    else if(islower(encryptString[i])){
        finalChar = (((encryptString[i] - 97) + rotNum) % 26) + 97;
        finalString[i] = tolower(finalChar);
        //printf("%c\n", finalChar);
    }

    else{
        finalChar = ' ';
        finalString[i] = finalChar;
    }

    printf("%c", finalString[i]);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: it would help to know what it prints instead of the right answer ;)

Comment: amongst other things, this line: scanf("%d", &rotNum); is not reading the trailing '\n' from the first entry.  Perhaps your code could be written as: scanf("%d\n", &rotNum);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few problems in your code:

1)

```
scanf("%d", &rotNum);
```

Here you are passing a `char *` to scanf(). Declare `rotNum` as int.

2) After reading the input `rotNum`, scanf() leaves a '\n' in the input buffer.`fgets();` stops reading input once encounters a `\n`. So `fgets()` doesn't read at all. Use `getchar();` after scanf() call to consume the newline char. Or better, read the `rotNum` using `fgets()` and parse it using `sscanf()`.

3) Your second argument to fgets() is wrong.

```
fgets(encryptString, sizeof(encryptString), stdin);
```

Here, `encryptString` is a pointer. So this will give you the size of pointer on your platform, not the number of bytes (256) that it points to.  Change it to:

```
fgets(encryptString, 256, stdin); // or whatever the bytes you allocate
```

Additioanlly,

1) Use a proper return type for `main()` such as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or equivalent.
2) Check the return value of `malloc()` for `NULL` to see if it's failed.
3) [Casting the malloc() return is unnecessary and error-prone.](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html)

Comment: I'm reading the man page for sscanf, but it doesn't make a lot of sense to me. How do I parse it into sscanf?

Comment: For example: `char temp[256]; fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin); /*input a number*/ if (sscanf(temp, "%d", &rotNum) != 1){ /* input failure, handle error */} `

Comment: THANK YOU. Now I understand how fgets and sscanf work exactly. This "fun" project just turned into a two hour project to get those two lines of code. Thank you a ton.

Answer (score 0):

as the man page of `fgets` says ,

`fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after  an  EOF  or a newline.`

So when you enter rotate number & then hit `enter`,the input buffer will contain `number\n`.
While number will be stored in `rotNum` , `\n` will remain in `stdin`.
So `fgets` will read it & returns without waiting for input.

Use `scanf` instead of `fgets`.
If you are using linux machine, [here is the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: But if you suggest using `scanf`, you should include the format string to read entire line of text with it.

Answer (score 0):

I made three changes to your code and it worked without any problem:

```
1. Use  "int rotNum" instead of "char rotNum"
2. Use  "scanf("%s", encryptString)" instead of "fgets(encryptString, sizeof(encryptString), stdin)"
3. Either use "int n = strlen(encryptString)" or "for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)"
```

You have to make some other changes to make it work for negative rotNum.

Answer (score -1):

Try `fflush(stdin)` before using fgets. This should clear the \n from stdin

Comment: Behaviour of `fflush(stdin)` is undefined, don't use it.