# Fgets crash in C

Tags: c, fgets

My program exits without letting me to write anything for the fgets.
[image]
[image]

I have the same structure earlier in the program and it works properly.

Comment: Do not post your code and result as image. Post them directly as text in the question.

Comment: Please put code directly into your question as text properly formatted. See the online help for how to format. Also, looking at your code, you need to show how `s2` and `oldb` are declared and defined. Finally, did you try using a debugger to determine what line causes the problem? That should be your first step.

Comment: Does `fgets` succeed? You don't test that. Is the `strlen()` of the string 0? You don't test that either and given that `strlen` is unsigned, you might end up indexing `0u - 1`.

Comment: FILE *f2 ; 
   char writefilename[1024+1] ; 
   printf("Enter the file name\n") ; 
   fgets(writefilename, 1024, stdin) ;
   writefilename[strlen(writefilename)-1] = 0 ;  /* removing the trailing '\n' */ 
   f2 = fopen (writefilename, "w") ;  
   
   if (f2 == NULL)
    return 5 ; /* Unable to open writing file */

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my C code skipping the next user input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353960/why-is-my-c-code-skipping-the-next-user-input)

Comment: "*`writefilename[strlen(writefilename)-1] = 0 ;`*" is a straight route into disaster if you not check for the string being at least 1 character long.

Comment: You want to put another `getch()` just before the `fgets()` to eat up the new-line entered to make the program swallow the character stored in `wf`.

Comment: I am trying to get writefilename with fgets() but it doesn't allow me to enter anything, it skips stdin and returns me that the file can't be opened

Comment: flush stdin right before the fgets().

Comment: BTW that wile loop will always be true regardless of what wf is.

Comment: @MOehm no fgets doesn't succeed, that is my problem ..

Comment: With "succeed" I mean that the return valuze of `fgets` isn't `NULL`. You should check return values of I/O functions. You also shouldn't mix `getchar` (or `getch`) and `fgets`, because both have different semantics. I recommend using `fgets`, which reads entire lines, throughout and to parse the read line (with `strtok` or `sscanf`, for example) when you need a specific result like "yes" or "no".

Answer (score 1):

The call to `getch` read a single character.  However, you're actually pressing two keys to do so: the character you're intending to feed to your program, and the ENTER key which sends a newline character.

So `getch` reads either `y` or `Y`, and the newline is left in the input buffer.  Then when you call `fgets`, it reads until it encounters a newline.  Since there's a newline in the buffer, it reads just that newline and the function exits.  That's why you're not given the chance to enter anything.

You need to add an extra call to `getch` immediately after the first one to read the newline and discard it.

Alternately, you can call `fflush(stdin);` to flush the input buffer.  Note that the standard does not support calling `fflush` on `stdin`, however Windows (which you're apparently using since you're calling `getch`) does support this as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
rf = getch() ;
while ( rf != 'y' || rf != 'Y' || rf != 'n' || rf!= 'N')
{   
    rf = getch() ;
/* Reading from a file */
if (rf == 'y' || rf == 'Y')
    {
        FILE *f ; 
        printf("Enter the direction to your file\n") ; 
        fgets(readfilename,1024,stdin) ;
        readfilename[strlen(readfilename)-1] = 0 ; /* removing the trailing '\n' */ 
        f=fopen(readfilename, "r") ; 
        if ( f == NULL)
            return 3 ;  /* Unable to open the reading file */

        fgets(s, 576, f) ;

        invalidcell(s)  ; /* return 4: invalid cell */ 

        /* Copying file into array and converting char's into int's */                  
        for( i=0; s[i] ; ++i)
            oldb[i/24][i%24]  = s[i] - '0';

        fclose(f) ; 
        break ; 
    }
But I have the same thing and it is working, it letts to stdin
```